# Is a group of order of a power of p a p-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

...And vice versa? 
What is the proof of this?

I'm trying to understand why the order of a p-Sylow subgroup is the highest possible order of p in the factorization of the order of the group, and it seems to depend on this question.

I honestly have no idea where to start...

Comment: Yes, the order of a finite group is a power of $p$ iff every element has order a power of $p$.

Comment: What's your definition of a $p$-group?

Comment: Like Qudit said, a group where every element has order of a power of p.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem that for any prime dividing the order of $G$ there is an element of order that prime?

Answer (score 3):

Given any finite group $G$, the order of an element $g$ will divide $\lvert G \rvert$. Thus if $\lvert G \rvert = p^n$ for some $n$, then every element of $G$ must necessarily have order a power of $p$.

Conversely, there is a well-known and very elementary [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) of Cauchy which states that if $q$ is a prime dividing $\lvert G \rvert$, then there is an element of order $q$ in $G$. So if $G$ is not of prime power, then there are nonidentity elements of relatively prime order. In short, if $G$ does not have $p^n$ elements for some $n$, then $G$ does not fall into your definition of a $p$-group.